# Content Organizer to route documents to another SharePoint farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, content-organizer, content-organizer-rule

Is there any way to connect to another SharePoint farm to route document using Content Organizer feature of SharePoint?

- If yes, then please explain how it can be done.
- If no, then what is the reason or justification that it is not
  supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i find the reference that routing across different SharePoint farm is not supported through Content Organizer feature.

Reference: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a65282e8-08e7-4b32-b81c-880f1fee5a28/content-organizer